Gemini Maintaining Chat History for Multi-Turn Conversations with Python Server and React Native Client
I'm developing a React Native app where I send requests to my Python server and get responses from the Gemini AI. However, I'm facing an issue with maintaining chat history for multi-turn conversations.
My Question:
How can I maintain the chat history on my Python server so that Gemini can provide context-aware responses for multi-turn conversations?
Python server code
@app.route("my/api/endpoint")
def get_prompt(userInput, root, isVoiceChat):
    try:
       
        context_message = retriever(userInput)
        model = GenerativeModel(
            model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-001",
            system_instruction=system_instruction
        )

        response = model.generate_content(context_message)
        chat_response = response.candidates[0].content.text

        return jsonify(response=chat_response)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify(error=str(e)), 500




My react native code :
const sendMessage = async (text, name, isVoiceChat) => {
    const newMessage = {
        id: messages.length + 1,
        text: text,
        sender: 'user',
        timestamp: new Date()
    };

    setMessages(messages => [...messages, newMessage]);
    setInputText('');

    setIsBotTyping(true); // Bot typing status to true

    try {
        const response = await getGeminiResponse(text, name, isVoiceChat);

        const botResponse = {
            id: messages.length + 2,
            text: response,
            sender: 'bot',
            timestamp: new Date()
        };

        setMessages(messages => [...messages, botResponse]);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching bot response:', error);
    } finally {
        setIsBotTyping(false); // Bot typing status to false
    }
};

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
